# eway Payment gateway no such entity with cartid Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, eway

We're in the process of upgrading Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.6

We have everything working except the eWay payement gateway.

Payments are processed as normal but after the payment is made the customer is redirected to an empty cart page with the error:

no such entity with cartid XXX

All other payment gateways work i.e. PayPal, ZIP, credit memo etc.

Looks like this is an issue with the official eway module but they will not offer any support.

error from logs below with stack trace

Any help to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

Have already tried everything online that references the error code but looks like lots of different issues can cause this code to pop up.

We had Mageplaza smtp and this is now also disabled as one post referanced this as a possible.

Thanks in advance

Site spec
Magento 2.4.6
Php 8.1

Tried placing order

Expected to land on Magento success page

Actually landed on empty cart page with error message no such entity with cartid XXX

main.CRITICAL: Placing an order with quote_id 7kwrwEc19cYADHzoyLPvlMYVwCkg1Poc is failed: No such entity with cartId = 37572 [] []

Stack trace:
#0 //vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php(36): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler()
#1 //vendor/magento/module-gift-message/Model/OrderRepository.php(93): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException->__construct()
#2 //vendor/magento/module-gift-message/Model/Plugin/OrderGet.php(87): Magento\GiftMessage\Model\OrderRepository->get()
#3 //vendor/magento/module-gift-message/Model/Plugin/OrderGet.php(66): Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Plugin\OrderGet->getOrderGiftMessage()
#4 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Plugin\OrderGet->afterGet()
#5 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#6 //generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/OrderRepository/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#7 //vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Email/Items.php(66): Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->get()
#8 //var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml(1): Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items->getOrder()
#9 //vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include('/home/988668.cl...')
#10 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render()
#11 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView()
#12 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#13 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element{closure}()
#14 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#15 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(578): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#16 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(555): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock()
#17 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#18 //vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(975): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#19 //generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#20 //vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(502): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->emulateAreaCallback()
#22 //vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(187): call_user_func_array()
#23 //vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(458): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode()
#24 [internal function]: Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->layoutDirective()
#25 //vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/LegacyDirective.php(42): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
#26 //vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php(272): Magento\Framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\LegacyDirective->process()
#27 //vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php(206): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->processDirectives()
#28 //vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(1116): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->filter()
#29 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->filter()
#30 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callParent()
#31 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#32 //generated/code/Magento/Email/Model/Template/Filter/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#33 //vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php(363): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter\Interceptor->filter()
#34 //vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template.php(380): Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate->getProcessedTemplate()
#35 //vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php(380): Magento\Email\Model\Template->processTemplate()
#36 //vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php(336): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->prepareMessage()
#37 //generated/code/Magento/Framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder->getTransport()
#38 //vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php(91): Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor->getTransport()
#39 //vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php(93): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder->sendCopyTo()
#40 //vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php(108): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender->checkAndSend()
#41 //vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/EmailSenderHandler.php(134): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender->send()
#42 //vendor/magento/module-sales/Cron/SendEmails.php(46): Magento\Sales\Model\EmailSenderHandler->sendEmails()
#43 [internal function]: Magento\Sales\Cron\SendEmails->execute()
#44 //vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(368): call_user_func_array()
#45 //vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(879): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->_runJob()
#46 //vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(840): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->tryRunJob()
#47 //vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(280): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->processPendingJobs()
#48 //vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->execute()
#49 //vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod()
#50 //vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#51 //generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch()
#52 //vendor/magento/framework/App/Cron.php(86): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch()
#53 //vendor/magento/module-cron/Console/Command/CronCommand.php(126): Magento\Framework\App\Cron->launch()
#54 //vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand->execute()
#55 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#56 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->___callParent()
#57 //vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
#58 //generated/code/Magento/Cron/Console/Command/CronCommand/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#59 //vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1040): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->run()
#60 //vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(301): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#61 //vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#62 //vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#63 //bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#64 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Undefined array key "file" in //vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php on line 36 at //vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:62)"} []

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a fix for the issue or any further info? I've got the same issue on 2 sites both using Stripe payments. I found this that appears to be related https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36334 but the fix is actually in 2.4.6 and this is when the issue started for us when upgrading from 2.4.5-p2 to 2.4.6 a couple of weeks ago. Tia

Comment: It's specific to the module and we've tried several other gateways and they all seem to have an issue in some way with Magento 2.4.6. I was looking at stripe and they say the re module is fully tested on 2.4.6 If their support is any good they should be able to fix it. We're close to having it fixed but have had to pay a developer to do it. I'll let you know once we are 100% on a fix

Comment: Hi Adam, I actually found the fix in the end but my sites. It was another plugin that had used a depreciated jquery function in an Ajax call. success instead of done. What threw us was I disabled the module in the admin when testing but it was still including its scripts in the checkout page. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Adam, did you get any solution for this issue? because I am also facing the same issue with the eWAY payment method.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. please rename the vendor folder
2. After renaming the vendor folder, you run the " composer update " command.
3. Run Magento Main commands: php bin/magento s:up; php bin/magento s:di:c; php bin/magento s:static-content:deploy -f; php bin/magento c:f

Comment: This is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

my solution
dev/grid/async_indexing = 0;
It works. So I don't know if it has any effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).